# Remove \xa0 from string using in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a list of prices from which I want to remove all space such that the `prices[0] = '2673.00'`

```
prices = ['2 673.00', '53.55', '1 478.00', ... ]
prices = [float(x) for x in prices]
```

I have tried various options but none has worked for me.

```
x = str(prices[0]).replace(' ', '') # Got error --> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2\xa0673.00'

import unicodedata
my_str = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", str(prices[0])) # tried  ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’, ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’ as different forms but got same error as above

x = str(prices[0]).replace(u'\xa0', u'')  # Got error --> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2\xa0673.00'
```

Please suggest a possible way. Thanks.

Comment: You may remove any whitespace with a regex like `re.compile(r'\s+', re.U)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is given, this will surely work:

```
import re
regexp = re.compile(r'\s+', re.UNICODE)
prices_norm = [regexp.sub('', p) for p in prices]
```

But if you have control over the production of the prices, a better solution will be not to print the floats with spaces. Just change the `locale` before you print them:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
```